# Possible to use laptop's keyboard to type in Android?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard

Is it possible to use a laptop's keyboard to type in Android? If so, how?

Note my current setup:

- Freshly unpacked Samsung S4 mini
- Prefer solution which does *not* require rooting
- Laptop running Ubuntu (Linux), with Bluetooth etc

<sub>Further: Any security concerns?</sub>

Comment: See http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3452225/connect-bluetooth-keyboard-android/ and http://www.xda-developers.com/android/use-your-pc-as-your-android-keyboard-with-pcbtkeyboard/, for instance

Comment: Maybe [WiFi Keyboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/WiFi-Keyboard/com.volosyukivan) or [Remote Keyboard Input Method](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Remote-Keyboard-Input-Method/com.emblementertainment.remotekeyboard) might prove helpful?

Comment: See this [answer on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/233848/80242) (our Ubuntu sister site) which has a detailed answer how to let your Ubuntu box act as a Bluetooth mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it in awhile, but something like AirDroid or the like could be helpful. I've heard of a handful of apps that work in the same fashion, exposing your Android device to a browser on the local network.

With AirDroid running you can connect to it on your laptop using the IP address of the phone and a port number. Something like this: http://XXX.27.21.11:3456

The browser window will let you control the phone. I used it a few times to write long texts/emails. It does a lot, you should be able to initiate calls, browse phone data like contacts, look at media, etc.

I just scanned a review of the new version, it sounds much better and doesn't require your phone and laptop be on the same network.

Comment: You could also use a standard usb keyboard and a USB OTG adapter. I've done this before. The adapters can be found for very cheap online, a few bucks. One end plugs into your phone's micro USB, the other can accept the standard USB plug on the keyboard. The adapter allows the phone to act as the USB host, the keyboard as the slave device. This doesn't exactly fit your request, I suspect you would rather use the laptop's keyboard instead of having another keyboard around just for your phone, but I thought it worth mentioning.

ICS or higher is required, no Gingerbread...

Answer (score 1):

Samsung phones above the S4 use a very cool app called "Sidesync". You install it from the app store on your Samsung and onto your computer from their website www.samsung.com/us/sidesync. Then you can connect via a usb cable or having both devices on the same network. A view of your phone appears on the laptop software and you can use the laptop keyboard to type. But you can do a lot more like drag and drop files.